# Does notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests or an equivalent exist in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, arquillian-drone

I have seen this used by test frameworks (for example, Arquillian) to detect when the dom is ready to be examined with Angular 1. Is there an equivalent way to do this in angular 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onEventDone` from `NgZone` should work for that

> Notifies subscribers immediately after the final onTurnDone callback before ending VM event.
>
> This event is useful for validating application state (e.g. in a test).

https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone

Comment: I think that this is the right answer, but how do I get access to the NgZone (or at least the injector itself) from outside of Angular?

Comment: I'm searching some time already but I haven't found example code and I haven't used it myself yet. This might work https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/14f0e9ada8b23e6cb4dd4cf4ce1127e9c9180476/modules/angular2/test/core/zone/ng_zone_spec.ts. In `beforeEach()` create a zone and then run your test in `_zone.run(...)`.

Comment: Ah, I can get the root injector by assigning the result of calling bootstrap to window.app. That makes it possible to get to window.app.injector from what I would think that I could lookup NgZone. I haven't figured out the next step, though.

Comment: Zone should allow to subscribe to `onTurnDone()`

Comment: I ended up grabbing it from the injector and assigning it to Window. window["MainNgZone"] = app.injector.get(NgZone); This can be done in the callback from bootstrap.

Comment: So, you got it working? Would be great if you could post what you've learned.